# Objective-C to Monotouch (.NET) single line of code convert

Tags: .net, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I have these 3 lines. The middle one, I don't know how to convert:

Source Obj-C

```
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [[UIColor blackColor] set];
 CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
```

Destination C#

```
CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
// ??? [[UIColor blackColor] set]; ???
ctx.FillRect (screenRect);
```

Comment: If you're converting for the screenshot on the previous question, this may not even be necessary as I believe it is the default. Try it without and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some googling, it seems like it'd be something like:

```
UIColor.Black.SetColor();
```

If that doesn't work, then `-set` is the equivalent of `-setFill` and `-setStroke`, so this should probably work:

```
UIColor.Black.SetFill();
UIColor.Black.SetStroke();
```

See also: [`UIColor` documentation on docs.go-mono.com](http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor/Members)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the full Screenshot code I was working on for anyone who needs a MonoTouch version:

```
    public static UIImage TakeScreenShot (UIView view)
    {
        try
        {
            RectangleF canvasRect = view.Bounds;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (canvasRect.Size);

            CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
            ctx.FillRect (canvasRect);
            view.Layer.RenderInContext (ctx);

            UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

            return newImage;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your code.I'm using it to create an image from a View. The problem is when the image is created the background still remains black. Do you know how to set alpha?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line you want to mimic the other behavior is...

```
UIColor.Black.SetColor ();
```

..or alternately, maybe ?

```
ctx.SetFillColor(UIColor.Blue.CGColor);
```